# Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send.Channel: awesome_notifications.Response ID: 0

Tags: flutter

can anyone please help me with this

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize('resource://drawable/ic_stat_logo', [
NotificationChannel(
  channelKey: "key1",
  channelName: "proton coders point",
  channelDescription: "notification example",
  enableLights: true,
  enableVibration: true,
  importance: NotificationImportance.High,
)
]);
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
  id: 1,
  channelKey: "key1",
  title: "title",
  body: "description",
));
```

i am trying to solve this issue but unable to understand

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.